# C++ Using a reference to a string as an alias

Tags: c++, string

Is it always safe to use a reference of an object as an alias? For example, a string:

```
std::string test;
std::string &reftest( test );
std::cout << "test before: " << test << "\n";
std::cout << "reftest before: " << reftest << "\n";
reftest = "abc";
std::cout << "test after: " << test << "\n";
std::cout << "reftest after: " << reftest << "\n";
```

Is there a guarantee that reftest and test will always have the same string?

Comment: That's what it's for.

Comment: "Have" the same string? They _are_ the same `string`...

Comment: That's precisely the concept of *reference*.

Comment: It is always safe as long as the object being referenced is still in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if you think of a reference as a nickname. Even though you're saying `reftest`, you're still *referring* to `test`. So, in short, yes.

**Note** that there are some limitations. For example, the following is not standard:

```
std::string &reftest( std::string("test") );
```

but this

```
const std::string &reftest( std::string("test") );
```

is, because a const reference can bind to a temporary, whereas a non-const one cannot.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley variable declarations. Like in the question. Would `std::string &reftest = std::string("test");` be clearer?

Comment: I have marked this as correct. While other answers are correct this appears to be most correct. Can you please expand on why the former is not standard? Isn't my example code similar to the former?

Comment: @test the issue is that `std::string("test")` produces a temporary object. Then the reference is set to that temporary object, and then the temporary object is destroyed and the reference is no longer valid. In the second case with `const std::string &` the reference remains valid because there's a special rule in C++ that says initializing a const reference with a temporary object extends the lifetime of the temporary object, so that the temporary object is not destroyed while the const reference exists. That rule applies only to const references and not to references.

Comment: @bames53 Thanks. That should be part of the answer, that if the object is temporary then the reference must be const because a const reference to a temporary object ensures its lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

They *are* the same string, just like when a guy named Robert is called Bob.

It is just two names for the same thing, like you say -  an alias.

Comment: It's actually kinda funny to say *they are the same* when talking about *one* thing, when you think about it.

Comment: Yes, *it is the same string* would be better. :-)

Comment: Of all the answers this was the easiest for me to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The two names refer to the same object.

Although there are some differences between the names. E.g. `decltype(reftest)` does not produce the same type as `decltype(test)`.

And as others have pointed out there are ways to get a reference that isn't legal to use, but in those cases that's because the reference isn't an alias for a legal variable.

Answer (score 3):

In your example yes, but there *are* pitfalls:

```
struct X {
  std::string& s;
  X(std::string& s) : s(s) {}
};
struct Y {
  std::string s;
};

int main() {
  Y* y = new Y();
  X x(y->s);
  delete y;
  // now, x.s is dangling, as it refers to y->s, which is gone.
  std::cout << x.s << std::endl; // <- segfault
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will watch out for that

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are both pointing to the same location in memory. Output the address of each variable and you will see this.